# Unable To Add a Reference To a D365 Package I Can See In Application Explorer

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-365-operations

I'm attempting to build my first custom module for Dynamics 365 Finance and Operations. I have a custom table Patron. I'd like for this table to hold PartyNumber values, so want to reference DirPartyTable, which is in the Directory package.

I can see the package in Application Explorer within Visual Studio.
[image: Application Explorer in Visual Studio showing the Directory pac]

But I can't see the Directory package on the Add Package Reference step of the Update Model Parameters wizard

[image: Update referenced packages screen, not showing Directory package.]
I'd expect to see one labelled Directory (Directory) as per Appliation explorer and I have verified that referencing Directiry (Security, Reports, Directory) does not allow my project to compile because the table DirPartyTable is not resolved when it is referenced.

I'm very new to Dynamics, so there's a good chance I'm attempting to do something the wrong way entirely.

Comment: Could you add the error message you get when compiling the module when referencing the Directory (Security, Reports, Directory) package? It may be the case that other references are missing.

Comment: It compiled. I'm not really sire why though.